# Dynamic multi-level menu in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently using the [`DynamicItemStart` feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx) to create a list of menu items dynamically and it works fine for normal button items. Is there a way to also dynamically create a list of sub-menus that will then contain the actual command buttons? I want to achieve a structure like this:

```
File
  My Root Item 
    Group 1 (dynamic)
      Item 1.1 (dynamic)
      Item 1.2 (dynamic)
      Item 1.3 (dynamic)
    Group 2 (dynamic)
      Item 2.1 (dynamic)
    Group 3 (dynamic)
      Item 3.1 (dynamic)
      Item 3.2 (dynamic)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare maximum number of groups (say 10) in your .vsct file - 10 Groups and 10 corresponding Menus, with TextChanges, DynamicVisibility and DefaultInvisible CommandFlags for Menus.

When you need to show a group, you add a corresponding OleMenuCommand and in the BeforeQueryStatus handler set menu command Text and Visible status.

For items you continue to use DynamicItemStart.